# FB likes of page in custom app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-likebox

Currently I'm developing a custom facebook app.

Simply it will list products from companies.

For each product (10 per page) I want to not-only show the count of the companies FB page but also like to show some faces with it (ppl who like the page). My idea looks alot like the FB like box plugin though I'm unable to customize its design.

One option I came up was to fetch all friends likes (1 x per day) and only show those faces, though this could become pretty server heavy due to that there will be a couple hundred companies. Which will eventually make an easy 1000 users = 1000 * 500 queries per day.

Somehow I can't find any other way to like "scrape" like-box (just need 5 to 10 faces per listing).